# Android application cannot be started using packagemanager in Android version 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, localytics

I have integrated localytics-titanium module (https://github.com/localytics/localytics-titanium) in my appcelerator application for push messaging.

On Nexus4 (Android 4.4.2), the appcelerator application is not getting launched on clicking the push message in the notification tray. DDMS logs shows :

**01-09 19:49:17.617: W/ActivityManager(639): startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=/com.localytics.PushTrackingActivity bnds=[0,597][768,725] (has extras) }**

The application is properly started on Samsung J5 running Android 6.

In Nexus4 device, PushTrackingActivity of localytics module is started but it could not start the main application activity. Code inside the PushTrackingActivity to start the main launcher activity:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Please help.

Comment: The error you are showing is a warning. It still launches the `Activity`. You probably have another problem if you aren't seeing the `Activity` being started.

Comment: Also, when you call `getLaunchIntentForPackage()`, the `Intent` you get **always has `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` set**

Comment: Disable filtering in logcat and maybe you will see some other relevant errors.